# Android emulator hosts file

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, hosts

I wonder how I could update host file on a android virtual device? Each time I reopen emulator it appears with defaul hosts file, so I pull hosts file everytime.

what I do now:

1. emulator.exe -avd %avd_name% -partition-size 256 -gpu on
2. adb.exe wait-for-device
3. adb.exe remount
4. adb.exe push %avd_root_dir%\hosts /system/etc

but next time when I start the emulator there is default hosts file. How to change hosts file only once?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Myabe you have to repack `system.img`.

It's under `sdk/systemimages/android-**/armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Please add more details