# Preserve modified host file changes after reboot

Tags: android

With the help of following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117715/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-android-studio-emulator-running-in-nougat) I was able to edit the etc/hosts file inside the Android emulator.

The issue I am facing is that the moment I close the session after editing the host file and opening the emulator again with  "emulator -avd " command (without -writable-system) the changes to host file are not reflected (which I did in the last session). They got reverted back to default.

Is this a known issue?

How can I preseve the changes to host file which I modified via adb push command to /system/etc/hosts files (during emulator -avd  -writable-system operation)?

I have already gone through these but got no solution:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20213/hosts-file-keeps-reverting
[Changes in Hosts file lost when not using -writable-system in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057491/changes-in-hosts-file-lost-when-not-using-writable-system-in-android-emulator)

[Android emulator hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383315/android-emulator-hosts-file)

Comment: I would also like to know the solution for this issue